# How to clear go_router navigation history in redirect method

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

On application start i have a few configuration pages (that can be skipped by user) that user setup once, and finally ends up in dashboard page.

Possible navigation flows (depend on what user already setup, and what skipped in the past):

```
'/' -> '/dashboard'
'/' -> '/language' -> '/dashboard'
'/' -> '/welcome'/ -> '/dashboard'
'/' -> '/welcome'/ -> '/language' -> '/dashboard'
```

If i go from `/welcome` to `/language` I use `context.push('/language')` to be able to navigate back - but i am aware that it can be redirected to `/dashboard`. so if i go from anywhere to `/dashboard`, i always want to end up with clear navigation history, so that if user click backButton on dashboard, the application should shut down and there is no back arrow in dashboard AppBar.

```
final router = GoRouter(
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      redirect: (_, __) => '/welcome',
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/welcome',
      builder: (_, __) => const WelcomePage(),
      redirect: (_, __) async {
        final skip = await ...
        if (skip) {
          return '/language';
        }

        return null;
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/language',
      builder: (_, __) => const LanguagePage(),
      redirect: (_, __) async {
        final skip = await ...
        if (skip) {
            /*
            * TODO MAKE SOME MAGIC HERE TO CLEAR HISTORY
            */
            return '/dashboard';
        }

        return null;
      },
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/dashboard',
      builder: (_, __) => const DashboardPage(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Hopefully, someone has an answer to it...

Comment: The only way I see is to redirect to a route that was previously on the stack. This will cause the stack to reset to that position in the queue.

Comment: Created an issue on github for this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116164

Comment: did you found the answer @Michał Dziwota i am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

I'll repost this answer here as well.

This is what seems to have worked for me. I admit it's kind of a hack.

1. Have a global GoRouter instance

```dart
GoRouter? globalGoRouter;

GoRouter getGoRouter() {
  return globalGoRouter ??= getRoutes();
}

GoRouter getRoutes() {
return GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const HomePage();
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            name: 'auth',
            path: 'auth',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const AuthScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: 'login',
            path: 'login',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const LoginScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            name: 'landing',
            path: 'landing',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const LandingScreen();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
   );
}
```

2. Create this function

```dart
void clearAndNavigate(String path) {
  while (getGoRouter().canPop() == true) {
    getGoRouter().pop();
  }
  getGoRouter().pushReplacement(path);
}
```

3. Then you call the function

```dart
clearAndNavigate('login');
```

Open to suggestions for a less 'hacky' way

Answer (score 1):

Love the answer by @Alfiepoleon on top. I implemented it and it works great for me. The only change I made was to **not** to pass the GoRouterState but instead access the functions I need through **context**.

```
void clearAndNavigate(String path) {
  while (context.canPop() == true) {
    context.pop();
  }
  context.pushReplacement(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward way to do this, which is an abstraction of [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947617/10871073), would be:

```
void clearStackAndNavigate(BuildContext context, String path) {
  while (GoRouter.of(context).canPop()) {
    GoRouter.of(context).pop();
  }

  GoRouter.of(context).pushReplacement(path);
}
```