# How to clear previous routes in GoRouter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

I am working on a application where user can create group and redirected on a message List screen. Now when user creates group i want to clear all previous routes and redirect user on a message screen.

Currently once group is created user is redirected on a message screen but with a previous screen state and we are not getting updated data.

Currently we are using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) for managing a navigation

Once group is created we want to redirect user on a message screen with a updated data.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947617/5295747