# How to clean Navigation stack in go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

My rout is this. leading/login/home.
It is just testing so I use push() from leading to login.
And I use pushReplacementNamed() from login to home.

Question 1:
If I use go() will it leave stack of route in navigation stack.

Question 2:
I want to achieve when after login, there is no way back to login from home page.

context.pushReplacementNamed('home_screen');

// this is my current code and it doesn't work. Showing back arrow.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947617/5295747

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`context.go('home_screen')`

It will push a new stack so you can't go back to the home screen.